# SQL Server database insert/update TCP notifications

Tags: .net, sql-server, node.js

Is there anyway to send some sort of message from SQL Server to identify that a table has been updated or had a record inserted into it? Preferably TCP but anything will do.

I know there is SQL Notification Services but this is no longer supported in SQL 2008

Just wondering if its possible to build a real time app that pushes notifications of table changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Service Broker and Query Notifications.

- [Overview (Service Broker)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms166104%28v=SQL.100%29.aspx)
- [Working with Query Notifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130764.aspx)
- [Query Notifications in SQL Server (ADO.NET)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9x04ed2.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can try [LinqToCache](http://code.google.com/p/linqtocache/) which allows to wrap a [SqlDependency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency.aspx) around any LINQ query, as long as the LINQ generated T-SQL is compatible with Query Notifications. It will work with .Net, not sure about node.js