# How to monitor SQL Server table with external application

Tags: sql-server, rest

I am developing a script that will POST to a RESTful webservice based on new records being created in a SQL Server table.

What is the recommended modern way to do this (SQL Server 2012)?
I have looked at triggers but it seems they are not recommended when calling external scripts. Most of the info is very old anyway.

I would like to avoid polling the table so that it can be as realtime as possible with the least impact on performance.

Script is being developed in Ruby but can be switched to Java / Python if it will make a difference.

Edit: The answer to a similar question is to use the Service Broker service. However it seems to be overkill for this requirement.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server database insert/update TCP notifications](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7038964/sql-server-database-insert-update-tcp-notifications)

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9x04ed2(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I've been checking out the SQL Server Service Broker but it seems like overkill for such a simple requirement.

Comment: To do this reliably you need some kind of queue. If you bind some kind of external process to a database operation via triggers you are asking for trouble. As soon as there is an issue with the external process (whether an error or performance issue), your database grinds to a halt, either errorring (and not allowing data to be inserted) or becoming slow (and creating other performance issues). Could you explain your bigger picture more thoroughly? Are you just trying to replicate/synchronise data to somewhere else?

Comment: It's a legacy invoicing system that needs to be upgraded to interface with a webservice and provide electronic invoicing capabilities. So when an invoice is created a new record is inserted to the invoices table. The original codebase cannot be touched due to licensing issues so I can only upgrade this by monitoring the table itself and writing an external module.

Comment: All version of SQL Server except Express support [Change Tracking](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933875.aspx) which is enabled per table. It works in a way similar to `If-Modified-Since`. The [CHANGETABLE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933874.aspx)  function the change type and keys for all changes since a specific version. You can use this to get the changes and post them

Comment: You should also reconsider the "real-time" requirement. Inserting a large number of rows could result in many individual calls when only a single batched call would be better.

Comment: How many changes are there per minute? How soon do you want changes delivered? If there are few changes, you could poll the table every few seconds and post the changed records, if any

Comment: There are about 1000 daily invoices, so yes, there are only a few changes per minute. However, this is the exact argument for avoiding polling. 99.99% of the time, there will be no changes to the table.

Answer (score -1):

A dev from my team has suggested the following:

Create a Trigger that generates a text file each time a new record is created.
My external script would run as a daemon and would monitor the directory where the text files are created. If it finds one, it will process it and delete it if processed successfully.

In this way:

The trigger doesn't run an external script, it just runs a native SQL command.
The script will not have to generate thousands of reads against the DB when reading.

Seems like the best of both worlds. Any thoughts before accepting this as the answer?

Comment: Please indicate why this is a bad idea along with the downvote

Comment: There are several serious problems with this, least of all creating a trigger with elevated permissions that writes to a *file*. Performance will be horrible, never mind the security implications.

Comment: In any case, SQL Server already supports change tracking in all versions except Express. You can just ask for the changes since version X

Comment: Could you provide your change tracking solution as an answer?

Comment: I checked out change tracking. I don't see how it can be used without polling, which is what I am trying to avoid: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb934145(v=sql.110).aspx